# Implementing custom exceptions in a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, exception, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

When designing custom exceptions for .NET, MSDN provides [these guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064.aspx). In particular, the guidelines state that a custom exception:

- should be serializable, i.e. implement `ISerializable` and be decorated with the `[Serializable]` attribute, and
- should implement the (de)serialization constructor, i.e. `protected CustomException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)`.

However, in a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) neither of `SerializableAttribute`, `ISerializable` and `SerializationInfo` are supported.

How should I sufficiently design a custom exception in a Portable Class Library that simultaneously targets .NET Framework and one or more platforms?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically, ignore that guidance - that is for full .NET, and does not apply to portable class library projects. Indeed, if we look at (say) [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.95).aspx) (which includes WP7) we see:

```
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class Exception
```

Frankly, the main consumer of that requirement was *remoting*... and that is not in huge demand now.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification, Marc. I suspected that this was the case (the guidance has not been updated for .NET 4.5 for example), but it feels more ensuring to get confirmation from a reliable source.

Comment: @Anders I've added some notes into the "Community Content" section - they might appear at some point.

Comment: Some of this is enforced at run-time, though.  For example, if you try to add something to the Exception.Data collection it will throw an exception on the full Framework, but not on Silverlight.